# Some features are not working in my ASUS laptop with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

I have an Asus X200CA-KX219D VivoBook (3rd Gen ci3/ 4GB/ 500GB/ DOS) laptop with  Ubuntu 14.04. Scrolling via touch pad and the *fn* keys do not work.

Can someone please help me configure these features?

Comment: I find it ironic that you've never used anything other than Linux yet still don't know how to ask help related to it.

Comment: @Larssend I have never claimed that I am a pro at Linux or pro at asking questions about it! :)

Comment: Re: Touchpad - [Try This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/335317/deactivated-touchpad-how-to-activate)! Re: Fn Keys - [Does this Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultimediaKeys)?

Comment: @eyoung100 thanks a lot for your reply! Actually I can't find any ON/OFF  option for the touch pad. Somehow Alt + F10 is not working!

Comment: Does your keyboard hava a blue Fn key between Ctrl and the Windows Key om the bottom left?  If So the Key Combo is Alt + Blue Fn + F10

Comment: Nope. That's not working. I can go to the "mouse and touch pad" though. But nothing useful there..

Comment: Under Mouse and Touchpad, is Enable Touchpad set to ON, under Scrolling: Natural Scrolling should be OFF, along with Horizontal Scrolling.  Panel Layout should have Edge Scrolling, i.e running your fingers along any edge of the pad will scroll.

Comment: There are no such options at all. Only mouse speed key is showing.